# How to find a document in MongoDB not by its _id and our own index?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

> studentRouter.js

```
 studentRouter.route('/:stuID')
    .get((req, res, next) =>
    {
        Students.findById(req.params.stuID)
            .then((student) =>
            {
                res.statusCode = 200;
                res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
                res.json(student);
            }, (err) => next(err))
            .catch((err) => next(err));
    })
```

I want to search an element in the database using the `stuID` but mongoose always searches the element using `_id` Index although I have added `stuID` as an index in the db. Is their any way to search it by using `stuID`?

```
eg- localhost:3000/students/stuID
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace your `findById` with this:

```
Students.findOne({stuID: req.params.stuID})
```

Doc: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne